# How to add a package from GitHub in Flutter?

Tags: github, dart, flutter, package

I need to use the latest source code of a package and the latest source hasn't been published yet.
What should I write into `pubspec.yaml` to get a package in Github?

The code below doesn't work. It doesn't download the package and I can't import it into my source code

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  carousel_pro:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/jlouage/flutter-carousel-pro.git
```

Comment: Did you run `flutter packages get`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, yes. Do you know which path should be of a github package? Default import looks like this 'import 'package:flutter_redux/flutter_redux.dart';'. May be there is another way to import a package from github?

Comment: The `.packages` file lists `flutter-carousel-pro`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, yes. 'carousel_pro:file:///Users/kvyrodov/Flutter/.pub-cache/git/flutter-carousel-pro-e8df71fa66dbe72fe770515737506e266d03a5fd/lib/'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186109/discussion-between-kostya-vyrodov-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Try restarting the IDE

Comment: Documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages

Answer (score 252, accepted):

### Example of `pubspec.yaml`

---

Dependency with the specific **branch**:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  carousel_pro:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/jlouage/flutter-carousel-pro.git
      ref: main # branch name
```

---

Dependency with the specific **commit**:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  carousel_pro:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/jlouage/flutter-carousel-pro.git
      ref: ea12e41 # commit hash
```

### Example of a file importing the package:

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/src/carousel_pro_widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewsCarousel extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200.0,
      child: WidgetCarousel(
        autoplay: false,
        pages: [],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Note: If your IDE doesn't see the package, try to restart it.*

Comment: Is there any way to use a specific release version of a library?

Comment: @Mehdico you can specify the version of a package you depend on. If you're asking about git packages, then you can read more about it here https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages

Comment: What about private github repositories. Let's say I'm developing my own package and I don't want to publish it anywhere, will that work as well?

Comment: @AdnanAlshami, I am not sure about this case. But I think if you have an ssh key for the repository on your pc, then it should work. Does it work?

Comment: use main instead of master, if you have named your repo master

Comment: IMPORTANT: the solution above with "url: git://..." won't work anymore because git stopped to support unauthenticated "git://" protocol https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/

Comment: Can I use tag rather than ref?

Comment: Because xxx depends on xxxxr from git which doesn't exist (Could not find git ref '5704c9ff23ed6ec6e0f3bd458333704423448960' (fatal: bad object 5704c9ff23ed6ec6e0f3bd458333704423448960)), version solving failed.

Answer (score 72):

The above answers are correct but I have added some examples.

So to use pub/package/lib without publishing on pub.dev :

**1. Local - Save in some local folder**

```yaml
dependencies:
  library_name:
   path: /path/to/library_name
```

---

**2. Hosted - Pushed on Github, Gitlab etc.**

```yaml
dependencies:
  library_name:
   git: https://github.com/username/library_name
```

Or to target exact branch

```yaml
dependencies:
  library_name:
   git:
    url: https://github.com/username/library_name.git
    ref: dev    #branch name
```

Or to target exact commit

```yaml
dependencies:
  library_name:
   git:
    url: https://github.com/username/library_name.git
    ref: e234072340    #commit reference id
```

Where '*library_name*' has to be the same as the '*name*' declared in pubspec.yaml of that pub.

Answer (score 67):

I will show this use case, where you want to access a specific folder in a branch other than main/master:

```
  amplify_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter.git
      ref: null-safety-master
      path: packages/amplify_flutter/
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me. I am just curious about what if we want to add multiple specific folder using this 'path:' parameter. How can we achieve that?

Comment: @UlaşKasım I have not tried that, so I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: I *think* you would list this entire dependency multiple times.  So if you had another package at packages/my_other_dependency, you would copy and paste all of this a second time but change the dependency name (`amplify_flutter:`) to `my_other_dependency:` and then update `path:` to point at `packages/my_other_dependency/`

Answer (score 10):

What's more, you can also use **tag** if you need:

```dart
private_view:
  git:
    url: git@github.com:xxx/private_view.git
    ref: 0.0.2 # tag
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is one Example

```
audio_service:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/kaushikgodhani/audio_service.git
      ref: minor #branch name
      path: audio_service  #Folder Path on Github
```

Comment: `path` is useful

Comment: But this won't work in flutter cli command. Path is not part of the git parameter. Any suggestion? As I need to add the script to my pipeline

Answer (score 3):

The above didn't work for me but changing the url to use https did:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_tflite:
      git:
        url: https://github.com/qookit/flutter_tflite.git
        ref: main
```

"main" is the name of the branch I was interested in using.

The first time I ran 'flutter pub get' it opened up a browser window to ask me for my git credentials too.

Comment: Same here, I had git:// before and was getting errors saying it couldn't find the repository.  When I changed it to https:// it worked fine.  I did have to grant VS code access to the repo then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the list of alternates:

As of dart 2.15, authenticated private repositories are now supported.

You can publish a package to a private repository using the standard dart CLI tools.

Dart allows you to add and manage authentication tokens to via `dart pub token add` and `dart pub token list`.

Some private repositories require that you use third party tools to do the publishing.

With a repo like OnePub (https://onepub.dev) you publish as follows:

```bash
dart pub global activate onepub
onepub login // onepub adds the onepub token to the dart pub token list
cd my_package
onepub pub private // onepub adds publish_to to your pubspec.yaml
dart pub publish
```

You could have manually added the publish_to key to your pubspec.yaml which is of the form:

```
name: my_package
publish_to: https://onepub.dev/api/jbbxpsdavu/
```

Obviously the url will be dependant on the private repo you are using.

To use the published package in another project use:

```bash
cd <my app>
onepub pub add my_package
```

This results in onepub adding a private dependency of the form: (which you could have done manually)

```yaml
dependencies:
  my_package:
    hosted:
      url: https://onepub.dev/api/jbbxpsdavu/
      name: my_package
    version: ^0.3.2
```

A big advantage of this method over a git reference is that running:

```bash
dart pub upgrade
```

will upgrade you to the latest version of the my_package where as with a git tag `dart pub upgrade` will do nothing.

This method also makes it easier for your team to add private dependencies as they only need to know the package name (i.e. they don't need to know the url nor the git tag/ref to add a dependency).

Here is a more detailed explanation of the process. It is specific to OnePub but the broad principles apply to any private repo and the exceptions have been noted above.

https://onepub.dev/show/86646173-a968-4281-af39-3c37d349bcdc

Disclaimer: I'm associated with OnePub.

Answer (score 1):

you can use path if your package not the whole repository

```
geocoding:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/abdullahalamodi/flutter-geocoding.git
      path: geocoding #refers to flutter-geocoding/geocoding
```