# How to get the ScreenSize from a Flutter App for Windows Desktop?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.width / WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.height;
is 1024.0*1898.0,

and DesktopWindow.getWindowSize();
is Size(0.0, 0.0)

on a 4K monitor.

How can I get the real screen size?
(should be 2160*3840)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently getting the screen size requires a plugin, such as [`window_size`](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/window_size).

With `window_size`, [`getScreenList()` or `getCurrentScreen()`](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/405e6c5476fbdfd3859cf2f8570b21afb692ea3a/plugins/window_size/lib/src/window_size_utils.dart#L21-L36) will give you screen information, including size.

Comment: The plugin is currently not available on pub.dev, so add it to your pubspec.yaml file like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022704/how-to-add-a-package-from-github-in-flutter

Comment: The readme links to instructions for including it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Media Query

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height will tells me the height of the window but not of the screen. But I want to know the dimensions of the Screen/Monitor.

Comment: @derChris the browser does not expose this attribute. It is a breach of privacy to yank these values from the OS unless it is absolutely nescessary, which it isn't for a browser. It should be possible in native applications.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [screen_retriever](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_retriever) plugin。

```
Display primaryDisplay = await screenRetriever.getPrimaryDisplay();
debugPrint("primaryDisplay.size: ${primaryDisplay.size}");
debugPrint("primaryDisplay.visibleSize: ${primaryDisplay.visibleSize}");
```